# How to Kill a Watch Service Thread

Tags: java, watchservice

I have a requirement to watch a HotFolder based on request coming from my UI
I have start and stops buttons on my UI, when I click on start my code should watch the folder and clicks on stop it should stop watching it. I am using watch service to watch HotFolder, I am passing flag from my controller to watch service to start and stop watching the folder. Please suggest me how can stop watching the folder?

Here is the code snippets:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/start", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView hotFolder()
{
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.setViewName("welcomePage");

    HotFolder h = new HotFolder();
    h.hotfolderTesting(true);
    return model;
} 

@RequestMapping(value = "/stop", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView hotFolderStop()
{
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.setViewName("welcomePage");

    HotFolder h = new HotFolder();
    h.hotfolderTesting(false);
    return model;
}
```

HotFolder.java:

```
public void hotfolderTesting(boolean flag)
{
    try (WatchService service = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService()) {
        Map<WatchKey, Path> keyMap = new HashMap<>();
        Path path = Paths.get("E:\\TestingWatch");
        keyMap.put(path.register(service, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE), path);

        WatchKey watchKey;
        if (flag) {
            while (true) {
                watchKey = service.take();
                for (WatchEvent<?> event : watchKey.pollEvents()) {
                    if (event.kind() == StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE) {
                        System.out.println("Created: " + event.context());
                    } else if (event.kind() == StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE) {
                        System.out.println("Deleted: " + event.context());
                    } else if (event.kind() == StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY) {
                        System.out.println("Modified :" + event.context());
                    }
                }
                if (!watchKey.reset()) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is for sure something you didn't mention, since i see annotations that let me think you're using some kind of REST based library.

Anyway, your code is never going to work. That is because you are basically turning the thread that answer your question into the watching thread, and that is never going to do your job. I would suggest a Singleto Pattern, write your HotFolder class like this:

```
public class HotFolder implements Runnable{
    private static HotFolder instance = null;

    public static HotFolder getInstance(){
        if(instance == null)
            instance = new HotFolder();
        return instance;
    }

    private boolean running = false;
    private Thread t = null
    private HotFolder(){
    }

    public setRunning(boolean running){
        this.running = running;
        if(running && t == null){
            t = new Thread(this);
            t.start()
        }else if(!running && t!= null){
            t = null;
        }
    }

    public boolean getRunning(){
        return running;
    }

    public void run(){
        try (WatchService service = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService()) {
            Map<WatchKey, Path> keyMap = new HashMap<>();
            Path path = Paths.get("E:\\TestingWatch");
            keyMap.put(path.register(service, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE), path);
            WatchKey watchKey;
            watchKey = service.take();
            do{
                for (WatchEvent<?> event : watchKey.pollEvents()) {
                    if (event.kind() == StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE) {
                        System.out.println("Created: " + event.context());
                    } else if (event.kind() == StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE) {
                        System.out.println("Deleted: " + event.context());
                    } else if (event.kind() == StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY) {
                        System.out.println("Modified :" + event.context());
                    }
                }
            }while(running && watchKey.reset());
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
    }
}
```

and then you call it like

```
//to activate
HotFolder.getInstance().setRunning(true)
//to stop it
HotFolder.getInstance().setRunning(false)
```

Comment: I am getting java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException at public void setRunning(boolean running) {
  this.running = running;
  if (running) {
   this.start();
  }
 }

Comment: Ok it seems that a thread cannot be started more than ones. I'll change the code to use runnables.

Comment: Still no luck :(, some time thread becoming null .. and some times not.. even when I click on stop button (which is calling HotFolder.getInstance().setRunning(false) method) still watching the folder.. (still logging that new file created in the folder.)

Comment: It should depends on the way you do things inside run. Try adding some prints to see where it goes in the code and see why it sometimes don't stop (which means it doesn't actually finish the while, it is stuck somewhere inside)

Comment: I think when we are passing true while may going to infinite loop, causing this issue.

Comment: Some of the things you have wrote can be put in the constructor, while some other might go in the run itself. I don't how how to test it but i can make a try at merging the two.

Comment: @user7076183 i integrated your code, now it should work.

Comment: Still it is not working :(.. is there a way that I can share my war with you so that you can run and see.. when I debug the code what I found was.. when we click on start button control is going to while loop and it is keep watching the directory.. it is not coming out of the loop..

Comment: It is going to run method when ever I start adding a file to that directory.. till that time (I am adding a new file or editing existing it is showing stepping in debugger mode..)